# Resize a parent and child window at the same time

Tags: mfc

I have two windows, a Parent window, and a Child window.

The parent is a `PROPSHEET_CONTAINTER` and the child is a `PROPPAGE_ITEM_IN_CONTAINER`.

I have a check box that when called does this:

```
void RandomClass::OnBnClickedCheck1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    if (m_bool == false)
    {
        // GetParent() Aug1 prevents the z order from getting messed up
        // SetWindowPos resizes our child window
        SetWindowPos(GetParent(), 0, 0, 500, 500, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);
        // MoveWindow resizes our parent window
        ::MoveWindow(*GetParent(), 0, 0, 600, 600, 0);
        m_bool = true;
    }
    else if(m_bool == true)
    {
        SetWindowPos(GetParent(), 0, 0, 600, 600, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);
        ::MoveWindow(*GetParent(), 0, 0, 700, 700, 0);
        m_bool = false;
    }
}
```

This only seems to resize the property page inside and now the sheet and the page, any way to go about resizing both of them?

Comment: `*GetParent()` - are you trying to dereference the returned `HWND`? You can't do that.

Comment: MoveWindow doesn't work unless i pass the value as a pointer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm guessing this is MFC and `GetParent()` is returning a `CWnd`.

Comment: @OmarMartinez: `::MoveWindow()` expects an `HWND` in the first parameter, not an object pointer. Assuming `SetWindowPos()` is actually calling `CWnd::SetWindowPos()` (does `RandomClass` derive from `CWnd`?) and not `::SetWindowPos()` then it expects a `CWnd*` object pointer in the first parameter, not an `HWND`. `CWnd::GetParent()` returns a `CWnd*` object pointer, `::GetParent()` returns an `HWND`. You are mixing APIs. Try using `::MoveWindow(GetParent()->GetSafeHwnd(), ...)` instead.

Comment: @OmarMartinez: nevermind, I see now that `CWnd` has an `operator HWND()` conversion operator, so `::MoveWindow(*GetParent(), ...)` should work to move the *parent window*, and `::MoveWindow(*this, ...)` should work to move the *child window* (assuming `RandomClass` represents the child).